# Why am I getting a ValueError when trying to extract and paste images in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I was working on my Computer Vision project (for school) on Jupyter Notebook using OPEN-CV, Matplotlib, and NumPy where we have to extract squares from images and paste it on other parts of the same image (using the range function in y/x axis). It worked fine but now it keeps showing me an error.

My code :

```
img = cv2.imread('Images/flower.jpg')
flower = img[2000:3200, 1300:2800]
img[0:1200, 0:1500] = img[1200:2400, 1500:3000] = img[2400:3600, 3000:4500] = flower

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('more flowers')
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

The error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 3
      1 img = cv2.imread('Images/flower.jpg')
      2 flower = img[2000:3200, 1300:2800]
----> 3 img[0:1200, 0:1500] = img[1200:2400, 1500:3000] = img[2400:3600, 3000:4500] = flower
      5 plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
      6 plt.title('more flowers')

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1200,1500,3) into shape (1200,770,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

### I'm not sure if this will work because I don't have the exact image you are working with, but try this:

This code ***should*** resize the flower array to (1200, 1500, 3), matching the shape of the destination slices in img.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread('Images/flower.jpg')

# Extract the flower region from the image
flower = img[2000:3200, 1300:2800]

# Resize the flower array to match the size of each destination slice
flower = cv2.resize(flower, (1500, 1200))

# Assign the resized flower array to the respective slices in img
img[0:1200, 0:1500] = flower
img[1200:2400, 1500:3000] = flower
img[2400:3600, 3000:4500] = flower

# Display the modified image
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('More Flowers')
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

When you try to assign the flower array to different slices of the img array, the shapes must match.

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1200,1500,3) into shape (1200,770,3)

I think something is just wrong with this image, but thank you so much :)

Comment: @chuubry sorry!